# What's the difference between compensation and redress?

Tags: legal-terms, compensation, poland

I read on https://www.thefirstnews.com/article/wrongly-accused-pole-gets-eur-286-mln-in-return-for-18-years-in-jail-19684:

> Komenda will receive PLN 811,533 (EUR 181,000) as compensation and PLN 12 million (EUR 2.68 million) as redress for the 18 years he spent in prison. The ruling can be appealed.

What's the difference between compensation and redress? If that matters, the case happened in the Polish legal system.

Comment: I suspect but don't know that compensation refers to economics losses like lost income, while redress is tantamount to non-economic damages.

Comment: Thanks ohwilleke, noted.